# Should the use of subprocess.Popen and subprocess.call be avoided if possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, imagemagick, wand

I'm doing a project doing simple image processing and comparison through the use of  `ImageMagick`

Right now, to execute my commands I'm using the python `subprocess` module as such:

```
color_space = ...
evaluate_sequence = ...
output_file_name = ...

convert_cmd = ["magick", "convert", "-colorspace", color_space.name] + queue + \
            ["-evaluate-sequence", evaluate_sequence.name, output_file_name]

subprocess.call(convert_cmd)
```

I recently learned there are Python wrappers for `ImageMagick`. In particular, I was looking into `MagickWand`.

Is there a large benefit of refactoring my code to not use the subprocess module in terms of performance, security, etc?

I think the subprocess call is more readable/simple than if I used something like `MagickWand`, but if there are other benefits I want to switch.

Answer (score 3):

> Should the use of subprocess.Popen and subprocess.call be avoided if possible?

Not worth it. The code you shared is a straight forward task that you already templated in python in a clear & readable way. Why complicate your solution with additional dependencies and complexity for a single quick task. Also `convert` utility works for you today, but there may be another external utility tomorrow.

> Is there a large benefit of refactoring my code to not use the subprocess module in terms of performance, security, etc?

I would argue that it's only the smallest benefit to performance via NOT invoking a system call, but including a C-API wrapper module that dynamically loads shared libraries would also be about the same. Plus, depending on delegations, it's possible that ImageMagick itself would invoke a system call.

For security, either way, your application is still responsible to sanitize variables. I would also suggest...

- Reading up on [Security Policies](https://imagemagick.org/script/security-policy.php) with IM
- Ensure that the `subprocess.call` can not be access by external resources. (i.e. If solution is on a web-server, move tasks to a remote queue worker)
- Improve error & warning handling. They are more common then you think!

**Arguments FOR switching over**

Common justifications that I can think of...

- Reduce I/O because the image data is already in python memory.
- Tasks are dynamic based on an algorithm (like meme generators).
- Common pixel iterators
- OCR/CV preprocessors

Again, you really don't have an argument to justify switching over. At least not today.